# Mount Gilead, Galaad or Gilboa?

Tags: translation-philosophy, judges

In Judges 7:3 which mount is it really?

- NASB

> Now therefore come, proclaim in the hearing of the people, saying, ‘Whoever is afraid and worried, is to return and leave **Mount Gilead**.’” So twenty-two thousand from the people returned, but ten thousand remained.

- BST

> And now speak in the ears of the people, saying, Who is afraid and fearful? let him turn and depart from **mount Galaad**: and there returned of the people twenty-two thousand, and ten thousand were left.

Then, [according to various commentators](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/judges/7-3.htm), it's **mount Gilboa**.

Comment: What's the BST?

Comment: @curiousdannii Brenton Septuagint Translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Galaad**
The word is [גלעד](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1568&t=KJV), גִּלְעָד literally, *gilʿāḏ* in the MT. It is written here as הַגִּלְעָד (the *gilʿāḏ*):

> Now therefore proclaim in the ears of the people, saying, ‘Whoever is fearful and trembling, let him return home and hurry away from **Mount Gilead**.’” Then 22,000 of the people returned, and 10,000 remained. (ESV)
> ועתה קרא נא באזני העם לאמר מי־ירא וחרד ישב ויצפר **מהר הגלעד** וישב מן־העם עשרים ושנים אלף ועשרת אלפים נשארו

Here is the passage in the LXX:

> And now speak in the ears of the people, saying, Who is afraid and fearful? let him turn and depart from **mount Galaad**: and there returned of the people twenty-two thousand, and ten thousand were left. (Brenton LXX)
> καὶ εἶπεν κύριος πρὸς αὐτόν λάλησον δὴ εἰς τὰ ὦτα τοῦ λαοῦ λέγων τίς δειλὸς καὶ φοβούμενος ἀποστραφήτω καὶ ἐξώρμησαν ἀπὸ τοῦ **ὄρους τοῦ Γαλααδ** καὶ ἀπεστράφησαν ἀπὸ τοῦ λαοῦ εἴκοσι καὶ δύο χιλιάδες καὶ δέκα χιλιάδες ὑπελείφθησαν

"Galaad" is how translators understand γαλααδ, which is the name the LXX formed by transliterating the Hebrew (gimel-lamed-ayin-dalet). This word is used consistently in the LXX for גלעד. If one assumes the Greek transliteration is the proper pronunciation, then Galaad would be the appropriate term in English. However, only the [Douay-Rheims](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%207%3A3&version=DRA,CJB) and the Complete Jewish Bible ([Gil'ad](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%207%3A3&version=DRA,CJB)) take this approach.

**Gilboa**
As the LXX demonstrates the Hebrew is גלעד, which is typically Gilead. The issue for a translator is Gideon's location where "*hurry away from Mount Gilead*" was spoken (emphasis added):

> Many interpreters reject the MT reading “and leave Mount Gilead” **for geographical reasons**. A possible alternative, involving rather radical emendation of the Hebrew text, would be, “So Gideon tested them” (i.e., thinned the ranks in this manner).<sup>`1`</sup>

For reference, the location called Mount Gilead is where Laban caught up to Jacob:

> <sup>23</sup> And he took his brethren with him, and pursued after him seven days' journey; and they overtook him in the mount Gilead. <sup>24</sup> And God came to Laban the Syrian in a dream by night, and said unto him, Take heed that thou speak not to Jacob either good or bad. <sup>25</sup> Then Laban overtook Jacob. Now Jacob had pitched his tent in the mount: and Laban with his brethren pitched in the mount of Gilead.(Genesis 31 KJV)

In Judges "Gilead" is problematic because Gideon is on the opposite side of the Jordan River:
[image]

Mount Gilboa, however, is in close proximity to Gideon's location. This causes some to speculate "Gilead" was an [alternate name for Gilboa](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%207%3A3&version=EXB). However, Gilboa is גִּלְבֹּעַ which the LXX transliterates as γελβουε, "Gelboue" (cf. [1 Samuel 28:4](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/09-1reigns-nets.pdf)). Obviously the LXX understood the two as separate and in the case of Judges, used γαλααδ not γελβουε.

**Gilead**
The Hebrew and Greek are clear and so almost all [English translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Judges%207:3) have Gilead. Yet, in addition to Galaad or Gil'ad of the DRA and CJB, there are two other exceptions:

> Send home any of your men who are timid and frightened.” So twenty-two thousand of them left, and only ten thousand remained who were willing to fight. (TLB)
> So now, announce in the people’s hearing, ‘Anyone who is afraid or unsteady may return home from Gideon’s mountain.’” At this, twenty-two thousand people went home, and ten thousand were left. (CEB)

The Living Bible is a paraphrase and avoids the potential of a geographic issue by ignoring the specific location and focusing on result: *send home*. In a similar fashion, the Common English Bible avoids a specific location by calling it "Gideon's Mountain."

If the name of the location is not in question, then the issue lies with ישב ויצפר which the ESV renders as *return home and hurry away*. The second term, [ויצפר](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H6852&t=KJV) is a hapax legomenon of dubious meaning and the first, ישב is from [שׁוּב](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7725&t=KJV) which means to return. However, the specific יָשֹׁ֥ב is considered to mean "is turned away" in [Isaiah 12:1](https://biblehub.com/text/isaiah/12-1.htm). If the hapax legomenon is ignored, the meaning might be *whoever is fearful and trembling **is turned away** [---] from Mount Gilead.* In this case, the passage is not necessarily a direct instruction to leave Mount Gilead; rather, it is more a statement of fact: [having come from Mount Gilead] those who were present and trembling in fear<sup>`2`</sup>were sent away, because of that fear.

The hapax legomenon צָפַר means to go in a circle or to chirp or twitter as a bird. So the phrase could be seen as *whoever is fearful and trembling is turned away, go in a circle or chirp like a bird from Mount Gilead*. Then 22,000 people "returned" and so there are two implications:

- Because they came in fear, they went in a circle from Mount Gilead
- The 22,000 who returned were all from Manasseh (cf. [6:35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%206%3A35&version=ESV)), Gideon's tribe (cf. [6:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%206%3A15&version=ESV))

The unusual phraseology can be attributed to Manasseh having territory on both sides of the Jordan. Some came from and returned to "Mount Gilead" on the eastern side. Others, from the western side are effectively considered to be from "Mount Gilead" as were their ancestors, until they had defeated the inhabitants and received their portion land. The conquest of the land is an essential aspect of Gideon's encounter with the Angel of the LORD (cf. [Judges 6:11-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%206%3A11-15&version=ESV)). Treating all of the tribe of Manasseh as one, follows the initial conquest where the half tribe with land on the eastern side were required to fight as one (cf. [Joshua 1:12-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua%201%3A12-15&version=ESV)).

---

<sub>1. [NET translator notes](https://netbible.org/bible/Judges+7)</sub>
<sub>2. In fact they were camped near the spring of Harod (7:1) which the [NET translator notes](https://netbible.org/bible/Judges+7) means "trembling."</sub>

Comment: +1. Excellent answer Revelation! Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct issues here. The confusion between Gilead, Galaad, or even Gilad is just due to different transliterations for the same Hebrew word גִּלְעָד H1568. This was answered competently by Dottard.

The second issue is more serious. גִּלְעָד Gilead located on the east side of Jordan:

> Joshua 17:5
> Manasseh's share consisted of ten tracts of land besides **Gilead** [H1568] and Bashan **east** of the Jordan

The Midianites invaded the west side of the Jordan:

> Judges 6:33
> Now all the Midianites, Amalekites and other eastern peoples joined forces and crossed over the Jordan and camped in the Valley of Jezreel.

> Judges 7:1 Early in the morning, Jerub-Baal (that is, Gideon) and all his men camped at the spring of Harod. The camp of Midian was north of them in the valley near the hill of Moreh. 2The Lord said to Gideon, “You have too many men. I cannot deliver Midian into their hands, or Israel would boast against me, ‘My own strength has saved me.’ 3Now announce to the army, ‘Anyone who trembles with fear may turn back and leave Mount **Gilead**.’ ” So twenty-two thousand men left, while ten thousand remained.

The trouble with the text here is that they could not be physically at Mount Gilead.

Ellicott suggests these possibilities:

> (1) to alter the text into “mount **Gilboa**” (Clericus), ...
> (2) to suppose that “mount Gilead” was a rallying-cry of the Manassites in general, for Gilead was a son of Abiezer ... the phrase “let him depart from mount Gilead” means “let him leave the camp of Manasseh.”
> One more conjecture is that Gilead is an ancient name for Gilboa (Schwarz).

Barnes offers similar sentiments:

> No mountain of the name of Gilead is known in this locality, and it has been conjectured that the right reading is **Gilboa**. Others think that this may be a form of proclamation customary in Manasseh.

Benson suggests another possibility:

> Not that mount Gilead which was on the east side of Jordan, for the camps, both of the Israelites and Midianites, were on the west side of that river, in the land of Canaan; but **another mount Gilead** in the tribe of Manasseh.

In summary, there are 4 possibilities:

1. There is a scribe error. Gilead is actually Gilboa.
2. Gilead symbolizes Manasseh in general.
3. This is a second Mount Gilead on the west side of Jordan.
4. Gilead is an ancient name for Gilboa.

Comment: Thanks again Tony! Cannot yet offer the bounty but will do whenever possible.

Comment: Happy to do it, always learning something new :)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 you should also consider Revelation's comprehensive and detailed answer below.

Comment: @Bach you're right. Too bad for Revelation that the answer came after the bounty was offered. [Here's the reason I'm not raising up another bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188481/364217).

Comment: @Bach another user (which I can't recall the name now) already told me that once. It's easier said than done, specially without understanding what comes into play. There's a decision to be made and no right or wrong. There's advantages in accepting it fast to the people answering (their time is rewarded faster, they don't need to think about it further, ...) and for me (no need to think about it further too, ...). So I've been giving priority to that when the answer is good and I understand the consequences

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew word in Judges 7:3 is גִּלְעָד which I would transliterate as, "Gil'ad".  It occurs often in the Bible (about 134 times) in such places as Gen 31:21, 23, 25, 37:25, Num 26:29, 30, etc.

The transliteration of this name is problematic because of the presence of the ayin which is voiceless (almost) and so can be transliterated by ' or, "e" or, "a" depending on how it and the previous letter is pointed.

In this case we have a shewa under the lamedh which corresponds to no letter in English but is closest in sound to the "e" in "deposit".  Thus, גִּלְעָד could be transliterated as:, "Gile'ad" or just "Gil'ad", etc.

In most modern Bibles this has been standardized as "Gilead".

Comment: Updated the question with another side to consider

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - be fair! That is a totally different question from the original!!  That is speculation based on editing the text - those comments are reasonable but still speculation as we do not know.

Comment: The comments to the question with @curiousdannii (which you might not be able to see now) lead to me updating the question including that part (which was in fact always a possible answer => "none of the mounts you're mentioning is correct. In fact, ...")